# Программа на Python не выполняет вторую часть

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы

Есть программа на *Python* по учёту автомобилей и водителей. 
Проблема в том, что выполняется только первая часть, а вторая часть выдаёт ошибку.

Не могу разобраться в чём дело. Если кто знает подскажите.

Мой код:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, license_plate, brand, model, color):
        self.license_plate = license_plate
        self.brand = brand
        self.model = model
        self.color = color


class Driver:
    def __init__(self, name, age, license_number):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.license_number = license_number


class ParkingLot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cars = []
        self.drivers = []

    def add_car(self, car):
        self.cars.append(car)
        print(f"Машина {car.license_plate} добавлена в учет.")

    def add_driver(self, driver):
        self.drivers.append(driver)
        print(f"Водитель {driver.name} добавлен в учет.")

    def remove_car(self, car):
        self.cars.remove(car)
        print(f"Машина {car.license_plate} удалена из учета.")

    def remove_driver(self, driver):
        self.drivers.remove(driver)
        print(f"Водитель {driver.name} удален из учета.")

    def get_car_by_license_plate(self, license_plate):
        for car in self.cars:
            if car.license_plate == license_plate:
                return car
        return None

    def get_driver_by_license_number(self, license_number):
        for driver in self.drivers:
            if driver.license_number == license_number:
                return driver
        return None


while True:
    # Пример использования программы
    parking_lot = ParkingLot()
    print('enter number car')
    nu_car = input()
    print('enter color car')
    color = input()
    print('enter firm car')
    firm_car = input()
    print('enter model car')
    model = input()
    print('enter first last name')
    name = input()
    print('enter age driver')
    age = int(input())
    print('enter drivedoc')
    docc = int(input())
    car1 = Car(f"{nu_car}", f"{firm_car}", f"{model}", f"{color}")
    driver1 = Driver(f"{name}", f"{age}", f"{docc}")
    print('Выберите соответсвующую цифру: 1-добавить в учёт, 2-удалить из учёта')
    count = int(input())
    if count == 1:
        # Добавляем машину и водителя в учет
        parking_lot.add_car(car1)
        parking_lot.add_driver(driver1)
    elif count == 2:
        # Удаляем машину и водителя из учета
        parking_lot.remove_car(car1)
        parking_lot.remove_driver(driver1)
```

Comment: Не работает у вас удаление машин и водителей, поскольку вы пытаетесь из списка удалять объекты, которые там заведомо отсутствуют. Рекомендую для начала изучить [приемы отладки](https://pyneng.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/book/08_useful_basics/debug.html), чтобы самостоятельно разобраться, что не так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я прокомментировал ваш код, проверьте. Но вам надо хорошо подумать над логикой вашей программы.

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, license_plate, brand, model, color):
        self.license_plate = license_plate
        self.brand = brand
        self.model = model
        self.color = color


class Driver:
    def __init__(self, name, age, license_number):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.license_number = license_number


class ParkingLot:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.cars = []
        self.drivers = []

    def add_car(self, car):
        self.cars.append(car)
        print(f"\nМашина {car.license_plate} добавлена в учет.")

    def add_driver(self, driver):
        self.drivers.append(driver)
        print(f"Водитель {driver.name} добавлен в учет.\n")

    def remove_car(self, car):
        self.cars.remove(car)
        print(f"\nМашина {car.license_plate} удалена из учета.")

    def remove_driver(self, driver):
        self.drivers.remove(driver)
        print(f"Водитель {driver.name} удален из учета.\n")

    ''' в данном вопросе это публиковать не надо.
        оно не используется и только отвлекает
        
    def get_car_by_license_plate(self, license_plate):
        for car in self.cars:
            if car.license_plate == license_plate:
                return car
        return None

    def get_driver_by_license_number(self, license_number):
        for driver in self.drivers:
            if driver.license_number == license_number:
                return driver
        return None
    '''
    
# !!! +++
parking_lot = ParkingLot()    # !!! +++ содавать надо ОДИН раз, а не в цикле каждый раз новый

while True:
    # Пример использования программы
#    parking_lot = ParkingLot()
    
#    print('\nenter number car')
    nu_car = input('\nenter number car:      ')
    color =    input('enter color car:       ')
    firm_car = input('enter firm car:        ')
    model =    input('enter model car:       ')
    name =     input('enter first last name: ')
    age =  int(input('enter age driver:      '))
    docc = int(input('enter drivedoc:        '))
 
# !!! +++ экземпляры этих классо надо создавать только
# !!! +++ если вы собираетесь добавлять запись
#    car1 = Car(f"{nu_car}", f"{firm_car}", f"{model}", f"{color}")
#    driver1 = Driver(f"{name}", f"{age}", f"{docc}")
    
    print('Выберите соответсвующую цифру: 1-добавить в учёт, 2-удалить из учёта')
    count = int(input())
    
    if count == 1:
# !!! +++    
        car1 = Car(f"{nu_car}", f"{firm_car}", f"{model}", f"{color}")    # !!! +++
        driver1 = Driver(f"{name}", f"{age}", f"{docc}")                  # !!! +++
    
        # Добавляем машину и водителя в учет
        parking_lot.add_car(car1)
        parking_lot.add_driver(driver1)
        
    elif count == 2:
# !!! +++  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        for car in parking_lot.cars:
            if  car.license_plate == nu_car and \
                car.brand == firm_car and \
                car.model == model and \
                car.color == color:
        
                # Удаляем машину и водителя из учета
#                parking_lot.remove_car(car1)
                parking_lot.remove_car(car)                               # +++
                
                
#                parking_lot.remove_driver(driver1)
# !!! для  этого удаления, сделайте что-то аналогичное                    # !!!
```

Comment: Благодарю вас!!!

Comment: @Abram удачи вам.